# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError despite removing problematic code

Tags: database, django-models

I keep receiving the following error even though I remove the problematic code from my models.py file. The problem first arose when I tried setting my primary key to a UUID field. Since then I kept getting the error shown below. Deleting the database and rerunning the migrations still brings up the error.

Here is my **models.py** file

```
class VolunteerInstance(models.Model):
student_id = models.CharField(
    blank = True, 
    editable = True, 
    default = 'No Student ID Provided',
    max_length = 255
)
grad_year = models.CharField(
    blank = True, 
    max_length = 255,  
    default = 'No Graduation Year Provided', 
    editable = True
)
organization = models.CharField(
    blank = False,
    max_length = 255
)
description = models.TextField(
    blank = False, 
)
supervisor_Name = models.CharField(
    blank = False, 
    max_length = 255
)
supervisor_Phone_Number = models.CharField(
    blank = True, 
    null = True, 
    max_length = 10
)
volunteering_Date = models.DateField()
volunteering_Duration = models.FloatField()
scanned_Form = models.FileField(
    null = True,
    blank = True, 
    upload_to = 'scanned_files' 
)
approved = models.BooleanField(
    default = False, 
    blank = True, 
)
```

And here is the error that I keep receiving.

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.CannotCoerce: cannot cast type bigint to uuid
LINE 1: ...unteerinstance" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE uuid USING "id"::uuid
```

Comment: Did you re-make the migrations after removing the problematic code?

Comment: Yes I did using the following code, but the same error keeps popping up.

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`